# Ruby: shorthand for conditional concats?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**1. Is there a simpler way to write multiple conditions like this?**

```
self.location = ""
self.location += geo["city"].to_s + ", " if geo["city"].present?
self.location += geo["regionName"].to_s + ", " if geo["regionName"].present?
self.location += geo["countryName"].to_s + ", " if geo["countryName"].present?
```

**2. And remove any trailing comma as well?**

**UPDATE:**
Here is the exact code I'm trying using Vee's solution below

```
geo = JSON.parse(open('http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=127.0.0.1').read)
fields_to_select = ["geoplugin_city", "geoplugin_regionName", "geoplugin_countryName"]
location = geo.select { |elem| fields_to_select.include? elem }.values.compact.join(', ')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer:** Join array elements generated from a filtered hash values, removing any `blank`s:

```
self.location = geo.select { |elem| fields_to_select.include? elem }.values.reject(&:blank?).join(',')
```

**Original Answer:**

```
fields_to_select = ["city", "regionName", "countryName"]
self.location = geo.select { |elem| fields_to_select.include? elem }.join(',')
```

Update:

If `geo` is a hash:

```
fields_to_select = ["city", "regionName", "countryName"]
self.location = geo.select { |elem| fields_to_select.include? elem }.values.join(',')
```

and to remove any `nil` elements from the array before `join`:

```
self.location = geo.select { |elem| fields_to_select.include? elem }.values.compact.join(',')
```

Comment: Any way to remove the last comma as well?

Comment: `join(',')` shouldn't leave a trailing comma.

Comment: I get a `undefined method 'join' for #<Hash:0x007ffc66244f90>` error

Comment: @vee It doesn't seem to work. `geo` is a `JSON.parse`

Comment: `geo.select { |elem| fields_to_select.include? elem }.values.join(',')`

Comment: @vee If all three are blank, the result is `,,` anyway to only add the comma if there is a value?

Comment: @Hopstream, add a call to `compact` after `values`.  Please see the update.

Comment: @vee That still leaves a single comma `,` if all are blank. Sorry for being such a pain in the ass!

Comment: @Hopstream, if all are blank then it should return empty string.  Can you update your question with the statements you're executing and your result.

Comment: @vee The problem seems to be that empty strings get allowed (it only removed nil)

Comment: @Hopstream, please see the update, i.e. last line with `reject` call.

Comment: The fields are joined in the order they appear in the `geo` hash.

Comment: @Stefan, you're correct but I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to imply.

Comment: `geo={"countryName"=>"Japan", "regionName"=>"Kantō", "city"=>"Tokyo"}` would return `Japan, Kantō, Tokyo`, the OP wants `Tokyo, Kantō, Japan`.

Comment: @Stefan, Oh I see your point and how you came up with it.  With these series of comments, I would assume OP would have raised a concern about the order both in question and comments.  I'm not sure if OP is after order.  But thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 7):

This should work:

```
self.location = geo.values_at('city', 'regionName', 'countryName').compact.join(', ')
```

- [`values_at`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) returns the values for `'city'`, `'regionName'` and `'countryName'` (in that order)
- [`compact`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-compact) removes `nil` values
- [`join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-join) joins the elements, converting each element to a string

Since you are using Rails, you can call `reject(&:blank?)` instead of `compact` to remove both, `nil` values and empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use also `hash_keys.map(&hash)`

so,

```
self.location = %w(city regionName countryName).map(&geo).compact.join(", ")
```